# What is the event after total calculation of cart item in Magento 2 using Plugin

Tags: magento2, cart, event-observer, plugin

I want to know the event after total calculation occurs in cart using plugin in Magento 2.

Here is my **app/code/NAMESPACE/MODULE/etc/di.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
        <plugin name="cache_price_cart" type="NAMESPACE\MODULE\Plugin\Product" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/NAMESPACE/MODULE/Plugin/Product.php**

```
<?php
namespace NAMESPACE\MODULE\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Product
{
    protected $cart;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart)
    {
        $this->_cart = $cart;
    }

    public function afterAddProduct($subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
    {
        $productInfo = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
        print_r($productInfo);die;
    }
}
```

it gives me cart item information after adding product to cart but I want to get cart item information whenever item price is calculated or whenever cart item is calculated. I am doing this because I have to add custom price (From third party) whenever cart item is calculated.

I don't want to add my custom price (From third party) on **afterAddProduct** event but want whenever cart item is calculated. Is there any plugin event that provides that works on after cart item is calculated?

Answer (score 0):

So **this is just an idea..not sure though but it may help you to get started**

> You need to add 2 logs in the dispatch method and in your plugin. The idea is there will be lot lot of events in your log file. You wont
>   understand which gets fired after your plugin. Now if you add a log in
>   your plugin too then you will know which gets fired exactly after your
>   plugin log.Hence the same log file needed like xyz.log. Same file for both logs.

`//Magento\Framework\Event/Manager - This is the file path`

```
public function dispatch($eventName, array $data = [])
    {
        $eventName = mb_strtolower($eventName);
        \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('EVENT:' . $eventName, ['group' => 'EVENT', 'name' => $eventName]);
        foreach ($this->_eventConfig->getObservers($eventName) as $observerConfig) {
            $event = new \Magento\Framework\Event($data);
            // log the event name here in a file xyz.log
            $event->setName($eventName);
            $wrapper = new Observer();
            $wrapper->setData(array_merge(['event' => $event], $data));

            \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('OBSERVER:' . $observerConfig['name']);
            $this->_invoker->dispatch($observerConfig, $wrapper);
            \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('OBSERVER:' . $observerConfig['name']);
        }
        \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('EVENT:' . $eventName);
    }
```

So in the `above code you can add a log to print any event.`

Along with that

```
public function afterAddProduct($subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
    {
        // log something here too in the same file xyz.log
        $productInfo = $this->_cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
        print_r($productInfo);die;
    }
```